# How does Citrix support SHAppBarMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, citrix

According to the 'Seamless Application Programming Guide' published by Citrix (link below), Citrix supports some of the SHAppBarMessage, but doesn't give any details on what it supports:

> Elements of the limited shell feature support consist of the
>   following:
>
> 1. Shell_NotifyIcon
> 2. SHAppBarMessage (Note: This API is currently not fully supported)
> 3. Windows that support shell features usually created by the Explorer desktop

http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/15599-102-664576/Seamless%20Application%20Programming%20Guide.pdf

Any idea what is supported or how to make it work?  I just want to get the size the the taskbar on the **client** computer (calling GetTaskbarPos returns the size and position of the taskbar on the Citrix client which isn't what I need).

Comment: Citrix I believe was started by an employee who worked on many of the remote desktop features within Windows itself.  This both allows them to support features from pure knowlege and the ability to know what to ask for support.  Many of the remote desktop features are also licensed to Citrix through a business partnership.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem related to your goal. Citrix is not exposing the client's taskbar on the host. It is taking API calls on the host and marshalling them to the client.

Comment: Yes, I would like to marshal the SHAppBarMessage to the client, OR find some other method of determining the same information.